# Where to store training data files in Django for a Chatbot?

Tags: python, django, pickle, chatbot

I am trying to display a chatbot that I created on a django site. So I need to load some training data (json, pickle and h5 files) into views.py file. But when I run the server it says:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mysite/polls/intents.json'
```

even though views.py and intents.json are in the same folder.

So now I am wondering where I should store these files and how to open/import them into my views.py file. Do I need to put them into my static files folder or something like that?

Here is the code from the views.py file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
import pickle
import numpy as np

from keras.models import load_model
import json
import random

# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())
    model = load_model('chatbot_model.h5')
    words = pickle.load(open('words.pkl','rb'))
    classes = pickle.load(open('classes.pkl','rb'))

    def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
        sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
        sentence_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in sentence_words]
        return sentence_words

    # return bag of words array: 0 or 1 for each word in the bag that exists in the sentence

    def bow(sentence, words, show_details=True):
        # tokenize the pattern
        sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
        # bag of words - matrix of N words, vocabulary matrix
        bag = [0]*len(words)
        for s in sentence_words:
            for i,w in enumerate(words):
                if w == s:
                    # assign 1 if current word is in the vocabulary position
                    bag[i] = 1
                    if show_details:
                        print ("found in bag: %s" % w)
        return(np.array(bag))

    def predict_class(sentence, model):
        # filter out predictions below a threshold
        p = bow(sentence, words,show_details=False)
        res = model.predict(np.array([p]))[0]
        print(res)
        ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.95
        results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(res) if r>ERROR_THRESHOLD]
        # sort by strength of probability
        results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        return_list = []
        for r in results:
            return_list.append({"intent": classes[r[0]], "probability": str(r[1])})
        if not return_list:
            return_list.append({"intent": "unclear", "probability": "1"})
        return return_list
        

    def getResponse(ints, intents_json):
        tag = ints[0]['intent']
        list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
        for i in list_of_intents:
            if(i['tag']== tag):
                result = random.choice(i['responses'])
                break
        return result

    def chatbot_response(msg):
        ints = predict_class(msg, model)
        res = getResponse(ints, intents)
        return res


    return render(request, "index.html")
```

Comment: are the files located in `mysite/polls/`? If you are unsure from which working directory your code is executed you can run `print(os.getcwd())` after importing os `import os`

Answer (score 0):

you can store your file in static, before that u need to add static files root in your settings.py file in root project. here u can follow the bellow steps:

add root media file so django can know where your files stored

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

add this code to root urls.py file

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

you can also add files in database through models

```
class ExcelSampleFormat(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=233)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/sample_format/')
    insertion_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.file_name
```

then you can read that file from view
from .models import ExcelSampleFormat

```
def readfile(request):
    employee_bulk_data_upload = 
    ExcelSampleFormat.objects.get(file_name='filename')
```